# Puzzling StackExchange Rules

Tags: discussion, feature-request, policy

A site about puzzle solving needs some ground rules.  Have any of the mods gotten around to this yet, because the Help Center page is just the StackExchange default one?

Something like:

## Potential Rules

#### General Rules

1. The purpose of this StackExchange site is fun.
2. Don't be a douche.

#### Asker Rules

1. Every puzzle must have a correct answer.
2. If the asker doesn't know the answer, it needs to be explicitly tagged as `solution-unknown`.
3. Hints should gradually be provided if no one gets the solution in a "reasonable" amount of time.
4. Asker should try to make the problem have a unique solution..
5. Any justified answer that fits the clues is considered correct, even if it's different than what OP had in mind.
6. If multiple users solve the puzzle correctly, the earliest post gets accepted.

#### Answerer Rules:

1. No answers in comments.
2. Answers must be justified in some form.
3. Answers and justification should be hidden with the CSS tools available.
4. One attempted answer per post.

Does anything like this exist yet?

Comment: Some of this content is already in the Help Center - for example, the [Be Nice policy](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice). The other page is the only one we get to edit, for which this question is a duplicate. That being said, _please_ post these thoughts there, too. That question needs more love, and it's gotten zero.